# How to check If input with id is not empty. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to check if Input with id is not empty.
Here is my view

```
<div class="form-group form-group-inline">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocName, new { id = "DocName1", name ="DocName1"})
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-inline">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocName, new { id = "DocName2", name ="DocName2"})
</div>
```

I've checked it before with if `(!(string.IsNullOrEmpty( model.DocName )))`

but there is two DocName's in a view and both must be inserted in same table if `!empty`

I want to store it in Db like this:

```
id Name
1  DocName1.Value
2  DocName2.Value
```

Controller is Empty...

but i want something like this:

```
var DocumentDb = new Document();
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.DocName1)))  
db.Documents.Add(DocumentDb);
db.SaveChanges();
{
DocumentDb.Name = model.DocName1;
}
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.DocName2)))  
{
DocumentDb.Name = model.DocName2;
db.Documents.Add(DocumentDb);
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And my Model...

```
public class Document
    {
        [Key]
        public int DocumentID { get; set; }
        public string DocName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your controller code?

Comment: i just want to check if input with id="DocName1" and id="DocName2" empty or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Model.DocName` is sent to the controller as a `List`. See Scott Hanselman's explanation [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

> FWIW – you don’t need the bracket notation if you’re submitting simple
>   types to the server.  That is, if your request contains
>   key=foo&key=bar&key=baz, we’ll correctly bind that to an
>   `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `T[]`, `Collection<T>`, or
>   `List<T>`.  In the first sentence in this paragraph, "simple type" means
>   a type for which
>   TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))
>   returns true.  This makes a handful of cases simpler.

Set your controller to something like this:

```
public ActionResult MyController(List<string> docName, int documentID) {

    foreach(string doc in docName) {
        // do whatever you like
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I think you have to change your View Model, instead of using this (I supposed):

```
public class MyModel {
     public String DocName { get; set; }
}
```

you have to use this:

```
public class MyModel {
     [Required]
     public String DocName1 { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public String DocName2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-inline">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocName1, new { id = "DocName1", name ="DocName1"})
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-inline">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocName2, new { id = "DocName2", name ="DocName2"})
</div>
```

After, in your action, to add "two different document" you have to do this:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.DocName1)) {
    var doc1 = new Document() { DocName = model.DocName1 };
    db.Documents.Add(doc1);
}
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.DocName2)) {
    var doc2 = new Document() { DocName = model.DocName2 };
    db.Documents.Add(doc2);
}
// Save invoked only if at least one field is set. 
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.DocName1) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.DocName2))
    db.SaveChanges();
```

You made a mistake while instantiating objects:
when you do this:

```
var DocumentDb = new Document();
```

technically you create a new object pointer.

when you do, after first "SaveChanges", DocumentDb.DocName = model.DocName2,
entity framework detect that you are "Updating" your existing object (because the pointer is the same).

Hope this can help.

Comment: i think i couldn't explain my problem because of my english. sorry. i want it keep in DB like above(updated)

Comment: What you mean? You need to know how to store these two fields in database?

Comment: After your clear explanation of the problem, I think that @jao answer is correct. I was thinking about a model with two specific fields. But you need a list of String and you should use an array. For your second problem (database), pay attention to Entity Framework and object pointers.